# Bootstrap nav is not collapsing

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

When i reduce the screen size the navbar items don't go inside the toggle, they are just stacked under the navbrand. Any idea why?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand | logo" href="index.html">Just-Repeat </a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
          aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div
          class="container-fluid collapse navbar-collapse"
          id="collapsibleNavbar"
        >
      
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbar-item">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">News </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">Contact </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">Privacy </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS or styling libraries other than Bootstrap? This may be a stupid question, conflicting classes could be the culprit in some cases.

Comment: @Andrew no, there is none.

Comment: Your navbar items are always being displayed (not collapsing on a small screen) because you have the `container-fluid` class included in your `collapse` div. `collapse` sets `display: none;` when the navbar items should be hidden, _but_  `container-fluid` sets display to flex, overriding the hidden setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically use the [bootstrap navbar template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) and substituted your values, hope it helps!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Just-Repeat</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">News </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">Contact </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="indes.html">Privacy </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```